# changing attribute table automatically in map composer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, atlas

I would like to add an attribute Table to the map composer, which so far is working, I also managed to display it as two coloums. I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 (Las Palmas) for a project where I have about 15-20 maps with the same extent, each displaying a different attribute though. I am able to use the atlas to create a seperate map for each of the 15-20 attributes (through visibility Presets), but I am not able to automatically change the attribute table accordingly in my map composer. 
The maps composer switches through the different maps, but always displays the attribute table of the first map. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that each map is displaying a different attribute? Does each map display the same layer, categorized by a different attribute? Or does each map display a different layer?

Comment: Yes, each map displays the same layer but always shows a different attribute (i.e. column of attribute table). Thus I would like the attribute table in the map composore to automatically update to the attribute its currently showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a data-defined expression to select the attribute table columns.

> Click on your attribute table > Item Properties > Attributes... > Add a column > click on the epsilon button (see image below)

[image]

Now use the expression editor to select the appropriate attribute for each atlas page. For example, if your atlas page names are the same as the attributes, use the expression:

> @atlas_pagename